# No Import Packages were found. Existing the Program

Tags: powerapps, dynamics-crm-online

"I am unable to connect to the Package Deployment tool. Can anyone help me with this issue?"

[image]
[image]

Comment: call microsoft support for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed the PackageDeployer using the CLI the PackageDeployer.exe will be located at C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\PowerPlatform\PD<version>\tools

The tool looks for packages in that folder. The Package should be unpacked with the main .dll file in the "tools" folder and the PkgFolder folder in the same directory. I did have issues with multiple packages being in the folder so make sure to clean up.

If you downloaded the Solution Package you may have to rightclick the .dll, go to properties and confirm at the bottom that the file should not be blocked. That might also be necessary for the .dll files the Package Deployer installed before you can first use it.

It feels like there has to be a cleaner process but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check the deployment log.
%appdata%\microsoft<package deployer tool name><version>

The name of the tool depends on what version of the tool you’re using.  All versions have the name Package Deployer in them.

You will find a log file in there with more info on what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Since I am facing some issues with this tool, I'm planning to deploy this through the GitHub pipeline.